# GFCI breaker trips when switched on

Tags: electrical, gfci

I'm buying a house.  It's an old house.  I had to put in a GFCI breaker for the bathroom.  It trips as soon as I switch it on.  If I disconnect the neutral it doesn't trip.  It is three wire coming out of panel but two wire at the light/receptacle in bathroom.

Comment: Crossed neutral? For a GFCI to work, this "hot" and this "neutral" must serve the exact same fixtures and nothing else. Some tinkerers think that doesn't matter since all grounds+neutrals tie together in the panel. ----- When you say 3 wires out of panel, do you mean the hot+2 neutrals that go in/out of the GFCI? Or are you saying 2 hots and a neutral exit the service panel (ignoring grounds)? If the latter, the bathroom is 1/2 of an MWBC which is 2 circuits sharing a neutral by design, which gives GFCIs problems - ask for help if so.

Comment: When you say "*three wire out of panel*". Are you talking about a multi-wire branch circuit (two "hot", one "neutral", and a ground), or a single circuit with a ground wire (one "hot", one "neutral", and a ground)?

Comment: @WolfHarper I've never run into this nonsense before, why would you ever mix circuits in any way? Is this a commercial practice or just knowledge used to cut a corner, yet again? You don't condone this type of work do you?

Comment: @Iggy There are times where two circuits will be in the same box (happens sometimes with lighting circuit being in the same multi-gang switch box), and all the "neutrals" will be connected together instead of keeping them separate.  While not technically correct, this mistake doesn't usually cause problems, unless one or both of the circuits are GFCI or AFCI protected.

Comment: The, maybe dozen is all, junction boxes I've done I had no trouble labeling for myself to avoid anything like this...specifically & purposely to avoid spread of damage & feedback. I don't see how or why this would happen. But, they do call themselves Contractors rather than Professionals...just to get another dig-in, you know it's my thing.